Issue with specific site
Browsing works well on my Ubuntu/Linux 22.04.4 laptop except one site. Images are not loading. I've tried in Firefox, Chrome, Blisk and even Edge for Linux but it won't work. I can see it has js-errors which might be related. And that may be because some js files are being blocked. The site does work on my iphone though. And I'm told it works on other OS.
The site is: knowledgecottonapparel . com

This is what the site owner says:
It is very strange and I have not hear about this issue before – not internally or from any customers.
I am using the website regularly and there are no issues – I use it via google chrome.
Maybe it is something to do with your screen/speed settings? Maybe you have sort of image/video blocking turned on? I am very sorry that I can not help more – but maybe you have an IT person to contact, as this does not seem to be an issue with the website itself.

I don't see any image with Firefox. It looks like this site is broken and there's no issue with your system. You can try to contact the website owner.

@A.L The owner of the site says it works for everybody else. And it does work on my iphone. I've asked a friend to try on Mac OS X and that works too. So for some reason it seems it does not work on Linux?! Can you try it on another OS or device?

@mook765 I can assure you it's not spam! What kind of logging from Firefox is useful to get this solved? And can you tell me how I can improve the question to not get it flagged as spam? This is a legitimate problem for me. Or can you suggest another forum?

@BenAndersen I tend to believe you, so I retracted the flag. I don't think we can help you with that issue at all, you should contact the site maintainers.

@mook765 But it's an issue with browsing from Ubuntu/Linux it seems. Have you even read my question? I've added info about what the site owner has said..

@BenAndersen Of course I read your question, why do you think I didn't. I even tested the site on my system (firefox) and get the same result. The site looks somehow broken. I also disabled addblocker, no improvement.

@mook765 Thanks for checking! Do you have any other OS to test with? I run Ubuntu/Linux on all my computers.. But from the site owner I understand it works for "everybody else" and I asked a Mac OS X user and it works there. And it works on my iphone. So... what do you think could be the issue?

@mook765 I tested in Browserstack on Firefox for Mac OS X and images are loading there... And also on Windows 11 with Firefox 130.

I tested the page in Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11. It looks like the gray images are placeholders before the final image loads in Windows. The final images don't load in Linux. The problem seems to exist only in Linux. Consider reporting a bug for Firefox via Ubuntu See How to report a bug.

I'll suggest checking you've applied all security fixes & other upgrades; as if your details are correct you haven't. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS properly upgraded is 22.04.5 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release, but installed systems upgraded a week+ ago).

@user68186 Thanks for testing! I couldn't report a bug that way as my Firefox is a Snap from Mozilla. But I asked a question here, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1463545
It's the same on other browsers on Linux though (Chrome and Edge). But I guess I have to start somewhere..

@guiverc Thanks! I have now updated to Ubuntu 22.04.5. The issues is the same though.
